# Determining how an object is cast inside a method with Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, casting, implicit, assign

How could Reflection be used to determine the ways an object is cast from inside a method?

Example:

Given this type, which can be implicitly cast and assigned as an int, float, or string:

```
public class VersatileType {

    public int intVal = 10;
    public float floatVal = 1.5f;
    public string stringVal = "words";

    // implicit convertions

    // ints
    public static implicit operator int(VersatileType vt) {
        return vt.intVal;
    }

    public static implicit operator VersatileType(int val) {
        VersatileType vt = new VersatileType();
        vt.intVal = val;
        return vt;
    }

    // floats
    public static implicit operator float(VersatileType vt) {
        return vt.floatVal;
    }

    public static implicit operator VersatileType(float val) {
        VersatileType vt = new VersatileType();
        vt.floatVal = val;
        return vt;
    }

    // strings
    public static implicit operator string(VersatileType vt) {
        return vt.stringVal;
    }

    public static implicit operator VersatileType(string val) {
        VersatileType vt = new VersatileType();
        vt.stringVal = val;
        return vt;
    }
}
```

And the given method which does some implicit casting and assigning:

```
public VersatileType obj;

public void CastAndAssignObj() {

    obj = 0;
    string text = obj;
}
```

Is there a way to use Reflection (or any other process) to determine how "obj" was cast/assigned from inside `CastAndassignObj()`?

I'd like to end up with a collection containing the Types **`int`** and **`string`** for the above example.

Many thanks-

Answer (score 0):

Reflection will do you no good here because it will always produce `VersatileType` and that has 3 properties of type `string`, `int` and `float` reflection won't tell you which one is being used. I think the simplest way to do what you want is either to add a flag (isInt, isFloat, isString) or stop initializing those values so you can say

```
   if (myVersatileType.StringVal != null)
       // guess we're a string
```

You can't use reflection because it does not create different types. There is only one type, which has three values, and only one of those is used.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to make this determination without running the code. Sounds nuts, but I need to determine the way that "obj" is used so I can use the information as part of a Unity editor tool, in a separate runtime environment than the executable that will eventually run the above code. I hope that makes any kind of sense.